# Programmatically capture X11 region with ffmpeg in C/whatever

Tags: c, ffmpeg

There is an input format option to ffmpeg -- `x11grab` which allows one to capture specified region and output it to file/stream. I'm trying to do the same thing programmatically, but i haven't found any non-basic tutorials/reference for ffmpeg API.

I wonder, how it is possible to open x11 region with avformat_input_file or something like this. Or should i do it with XCopyArea/etc?

(Any programming language will satisfy)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to capture video from the desktop or do you want to capture and encode video? I'm trying to understand if FFmpeg is really a key component of your question. If you would just like to see what magic FFmpeg uses in order to capture video, examine the FFmpeg source code file libavdevice/x11grab.c.

Answer (score -1):

There are many applications that take a screenshot. Major hint: it's open source, use the source. If you can't find the code in ffmpeg, any example application will do:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-screenshot/tree/src/screenshot-utils.c#n425

This is gnome-screenshot source code. This example uses gdk_get_default_root_window().